# QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream for creating purchase order in QB desktop

Tags: python, odoo, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have been using sending datas from python to QB desktop version. In that while creating for purchase orders,I am facing this issue, I have taken so many attempts and still I don't know how to resolve this error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <PurchaseOrderAddRq>
      <PurchaseOrderAdd>
        <VendorRef>
          <FullName>John</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <TemplateRef>
          <FullName>Custom Purchase Order</FullName>
        </TemplateRef>
        <RefNumber>900</RefNumber>
        <PurchaseOrderLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>Computer Cases</ItemRef>
          <Desc>Computer Cases</Desc>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Rate>20.0</Rate>
          <Amount>100.00</Amount>
        </PurchaseOrderLineAdd>
      </PurchaseOrderAdd>
    </PurchaseOrderAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

These problems normally occurs by giving wrong tags. In your part, under purchase order line add tag, the item ref should contain another tag inside it with FullName of the product item.

Comment: Yes, I have misplaced the tags.